# String operation -- Easiest way C#

Tags: c#

What is the Best way to Implement the below scenario

```
string sample = "Mountain View XX,Lake"
```

Am expecting 2 scenarios as  o/p

**Mountain View
Lake**

i can get the Lake by `sample.split[','][1]`

what is the best way i can get the `Mountain View ignoring XX`

i tried with **multiple splits and concatenating them also with lastIndex of** !!!

So is there any other easier way ?

Comment: what you mean _easier way_?

Comment: i want to know what will be the way you code to get the 0/p !!

Comment: Can you decide the string input? If you could use `"Mountain View {0},Lake"` instead, you can switch to `string.Format`. If you just have that: `"Mountain View XX,Lake".Replace("XX,", "");`

Comment: @Laoujin unfortunately No

Comment: @GrantWinney yes it does change

Comment: @Peru: Let me be clear. From  "Mountain View XX,Lake" you expect  "Mountain View ,Lake" or "Mountain View Lake" or "Mountain View"?

Comment: Please view my answer below.  I do think it is the best option on here.

Answer (score 1):

A [`string.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method works fine:

```
sample = sample.Substring(0, sample.IndexOf(","));
```

There is also the `string.LastIndexOf` to get until the last ocurrency the of a substring, for sample:

```
sample = sample.Substring(0, sample.LastIndexOf(","));
```

In your sample, both will work at the same because there is only a `,` char.

And after it, you could remove until the last  space char.

```
sample = sample.Substring(0, sample.LastIndexOf(" "));
```

Comment: Doesnt it return Mountain View XX ? i need only Mountain View

Answer (score 0):

Using [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

```
sample= sample.Replace("XX", "");
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.  Please read the entire question before answering.

Comment: @AdamHeeg: That's what I understood from the question!!! Please let me know if anything needs changing?

Comment: Your solution removes XX, but will leave the rest of the string, (Lake).  He wants only Mountain View returned.

Answer (score 0):

try to use regular expressions. (\w+\s+?\w+)\s+?XX\,(\w+)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx
group 1 contains`Mountain View`
group 2 contains`Lake`

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried with multiple splits. You can specify multiple separators in  a single `string.Split()`:

```
var parts
    = sample.Split(new[] { "XX", "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Now you've got two pieces:

```
var part1 = parts[0];  // Mountain View
var part2 = parts[1];  // Lake
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you want to remove that exact part of the string, but here are some different ways of doing it for that exact string:

```
string sample = "Mountain View XX,Lake"

// option 1
string removed = sample.Remove(14, 3);

// option 2
string replaced = sample.Replace("XX,", String.Empty);

// option 3
string[] parts = sample.Split(',');
parts[0] = parts[0].Substring(0, 14);
string concatenated = String.Concat(parts);
```

If the `XX` part of the string is really something else, like a street number, then you would need something to determine how much of the string to remove. Here are some examples:

```
string sample = "Mountain View 123,Lake"

// option 1; remove digits followed by a comma
string replaced = Regex.Replace(sample, "\d+,", String.Empty);

// option 2; remove what's after the last space in the part before the comma
string[] parts = sample.Split(',');
parts[0] = parts[0].Substring(0, parts[0].LastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
string concatenated = String.Concat(parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've left a lot out.  Is XX always literally XX?  Are you guaranteed that exact format or are you trusting user input?  If you know you want all the beginning characters up until you hit a double capital letter combo you could do a very simple regex.  I'd have to look it up since it has been years since I used those, but it would be super simple.

This does the trick.  It does include the space before the two XX's.  I am assuming the XX's can be any capital letters.

```
    Regex reg;
    reg = new Regex(".{1,}(?=[A-Z]{2})");
    var output = reg.Match("Mountain View XX, Lake");
    string text = output.Value;
```

You can test it out here:
http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html
and learn more about regular expressions here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go with:

```
string sample = "Mountain View XX,Lake";
Console.WriteLine(sample.Split(',')[1]);// Lake
Console.WriteLine(sample.Remove(sample.IndexOf("XX,")).Trim()); // Mountain View
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/RizzzC

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe do something like this:

```
public static string[] MyCustomSplit(string input, List<string> reservedWords)
{
    List<string> outputLines = new List<string>();

    string[] lines = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            List<string> lineParts = new List<string>();

            foreach (string part in parts)
            {
                if (!reservedWords.Contains(part))
                {
                    lineParts.Add(part);
                }
            }

            outputLines.Add(string.Join(" ", lineParts.ToArray()));
        }
    }

    return outputLines.ToArray();
}
```

and then

```
string sample = "Mountain View XX,Lake";
List<string> reservedWords = new List<string>() { "XX" };
string[] test = MyCustomSplit(sample, reservedWords);
```

which results with:

```
string[0] = Mountain View
string[1] = Lake
```

Or something like this:

```
public static string[] MyCustomSplitAndCleanup(string input)
{
    List<string> outputLines = new List<string>();

    string[] lines = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            List<string> lineParts = new List<string>();

            for (int index = 0; index < parts.Length; index++ )
            {
                string part = parts[index];

                int numericValue = 0;

                bool validPart = true;

                if (int.TryParse(part, out numericValue))
                {
                    if (index == 0 || index == parts.Length - 1)
                    {
                        validPart = false;
                    }
                }

                if (validPart)
                {
                    lineParts.Add(part);
                }
            }

            outputLines.Add(string.Join(" ", lineParts.ToArray()));
        }
    }

    return outputLines.ToArray();
}
```

which covers this:

```
string sample1 = "Mountain View 32,Lake";
string sample2 = "17 Park place,Something";

string[] test1 = MyCustomSplitAndCleanup(sample1);
string[] test2 = MyCustomSplitAndCleanup(sample2);
```